# Active button on android to call method

Tags: android, button

I have button than call method play stream like this:

```
// method for play stream after stop it.
    public void startradio(View v) {
        try{
            if(mp.isPlaying()){
                return;
            }
               mp.start();
        } catch(IllegalStateException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

and I define button like this:

```
Button PlayBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
```

Now I want when click on the `PlayBtn` I want to start that function by using this way:

`setOnClickListener`

**Edit:**

my all code like this:

```
package com.example.kam;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public MediaPlayer mp;
    boolean isPrepared = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        synchronized(this){
            isPrepared = false;
        }
    }

    protected void onResume (){
        super.onResume();

        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mp.setDataSource("http://radio.arabhosters.com:8015/");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } //also consider mp.prepareAsync().
        // defult start stream when start App.
        mp.start();
    }

    // method for play stream after stop it.
        public void startradio(View v) {
            try{
                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    return;
                }
                   mp.start();
            } catch(IllegalStateException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }

    // method for pause stream. 
    public void pauseradio(View v) {
        mp.pause();
    }

    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return mp.isPlaying();
    }

    public boolean isLooping() {
        return mp.isLooping();
    }

    public void setLooping(boolean isLooping) {
        mp.setLooping(isLooping);
    }

    public void setVolume(float volumeLeft, float volumeRight) {
        mp.setVolume(volumeLeft, volumeRight);
    }

    // method for stop stream.
    public void stopradio(View v) {
        if(mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.stop();
        }
        mp.release();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: show the code related media player(mp)

Comment: @Cobra Ajgar i will update my post

Comment: it was without button and setOnClickListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    public MediaPlayer mp;
    boolean isPrepared = false;
    Button PlayBtn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        PlayBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        PlayBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
      try {
            mp.setDataSource("http://radio.arabhosters.com:8015/");
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
     if(v == PlayBtn){
         start();
      }
     else if(v == PauseBtn){
          pause();
      }
     else if(v == StopBtn){
          stop();
      }
    }
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        synchronized(this){
            isPrepared = false;
        }
    }



    // method for play stream after stop it.
        public void start() {
            try{
                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    return;
                }
                   mp.start();
            } catch(IllegalStateException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }

    // method for pause stream. 
    public void pause() {
        mp.pause();
    }

    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return mp.isPlaying();
    }

    public boolean isLooping() {
        return mp.isLooping();
    }

    public void setLooping(boolean isLooping) {
        mp.setLooping(isLooping);
    }

    public void setVolume(float volumeLeft, float volumeRight) {
        mp.setVolume(volumeLeft, volumeRight);
    }

    // method for stop stream.
    public void stop() {
        if(mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.stop();
        }
        mp.release();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

}
```

Create a Button for `Pause` and `Stop` your mediaplayer

Comment: i try but show me this message :- **Unfortunately, RadioStream has Stopped**

Comment: yes :) thank you very much i will get some of your code for me, thank

Answer (score 0):

```
Button PlayBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
PlayBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startradio(v);
    }
});
```

Comment: i try but show this error `unfortunately, RadioApp has stopped.`

Answer (score 0):

```
PlayBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
//to do ur function
}
});
```

Comment: i try but show this error `unfortunately, RadioApp has stopped.`

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code:

```
Button PlayBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
PlayBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startradio(v);
    }
});
```

I'm not sure why you need `View v` in your `startradio` method; you can remove it from the method declaration and the call.

Comment: i try but show this error `unfortunately, RadioApp has stopped.`

Answer (score 0):

1- implement your activity with `onClickListener` (which should be view not dialog)

2-

```
Button PlayBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
   playBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

3-

```
@override 
   public void onClick(View v)
    {
       try{
        if(mp.isPlaying()){
            return;
        }
           mp.start();
    } catch(IllegalStateException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Update:-

put this

```
mp = new MediaPlayer();
```

inside `onCreate().` remove from `onResume()`

//

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    public MediaPlayer mp;
    boolean isPrepared = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
      Button PlayBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        PlayBtn .setonClickListener(this);


    }

@override
public void onClick(View v)
{
startradio(v);
}

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        synchronized(this){
            isPrepared = false;
        }
    }

    protected void onResume (){
        super.onResume();

        try {
            mp.setDataSource("http://radio.arabhosters.com:8015/");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } //also consider mp.prepareAsync().
        // defult start stream when start App.
        mp.start();
    }

    // method for play stream after stop it.
        public void startradio(View v) {
            try{
                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    return;
                }
                   mp.start();
            } catch(IllegalStateException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }

    // method for pause stream. 
    public void pauseradio(View v) {
        mp.pause();
    }

    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return mp.isPlaying();
    }

    public boolean isLooping() {
        return mp.isLooping();
    }

    public void setLooping(boolean isLooping) {
        mp.setLooping(isLooping);
    }

    public void setVolume(float volumeLeft, float volumeRight) {
        mp.setVolume(volumeLeft, volumeRight);
    }

    // method for stop stream.
    public void stopradio(View v) {
        if(mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.stop();
        }
        mp.release();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: automatically your activity will give it place just write yourActivity  implements onClickListeren

Comment: this problem was show :- **The method setonClickListener(MainActivity) is undefined for the type Button**

Comment: this spelling mistake only btn.setOnClickListener(this); try this